# Having problem sending http request from service worker in Chrome extension (Failed to fetch)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors, fetch

I'm trying to develop a new Chrome extension based on its last version (MV2), and trying to send a request to a remote server using a fetch request from the service worker. The fetch request should be fired once the popup is shown.

**The problem is** that I get a Failed to fetch error. I doubt that it's a cors error, as this flow (with some changes made due to the upgrade from version 2 to version 3 of the manifest) worked before.

The manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
  },
  "author": "Eyal",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "test.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "eventsPage.js"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    { "resources": ["*.png"], "matches": ["*://*/*"] }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

The popup.js code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      type: "configuration",
    },
    function (response) {
      res = response.res;
      page = response.page;
      console.log(res);
      if (page == "main") {
        main_page(res);
      } else {
        showPage("welcome");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Where the configuration (server url and api key) are stored in chrome storage after setting it in the options page. The helper functions are all working.

The service worker code:

```js
function send(method, uri, body, callback) {
  getConfiguration((conf) => {
    if (!isConfigured(conf)) {
      if (callback) {
        callback({ ok: false, data: "Server options not set" });
      }
      return;
    }
    const req = getFullRequestUrl(conf.server, uri);
    let p = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: conf.apiKey,
      },
      cache: "no-cache",
      method: method,
    };
    fetch(req, p)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (callback) {
          callback({ ok: true, data: data });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (callback) {
          callback({ ok: false, data: error.message });
        }
      });
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((data, sender, sendResponse) => {
  let responseObj = null;
  if (data.type === "configuration") {
    getConfiguration((conf) => {
      if (isConfigured(conf)) {
        send("GET", "test", null, (res) => {
          sendResponse({ res: res, page: "main" });
        });
      } else {
        sendResponse({ res: null, page: "welcome" });
      }
    });
  }
  return true;
});
```

Tried changing the host permissions field to be the exact URL of the server - didn't work.

Tried to make the fetch directly from the listener - didn't work.

Comment: Debug the code. Set a breakpoint and step through the execution. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried debugging, but the debugger won't stop on any of my breakpoints on lines inside a callback function. Just jumps to the end of the function. And all the errors are just "Failed to fetch"

Comment: Reverted to manifest v2 and left the code as it is and it worked fine, so the problem is only in the shift to manifest v3. Did Google add some logic that might cause this?